# JSP não reconhece Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Estou a algum tempo tentando descobrir o pq minha página JSP não reconhece o CSS do Twitter Bootstrap.
Os que achei na internet já tentei e nada.
A referência ficou assim para o CSS:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
```

<kbd>[image: JSP não reconhece Twitter Bootstrap]</kbd>

Obrigado

Comment: Ele encontra outros scripts e css?

Comment: então, acabei de criar um CSS teste, alterando apenas a cor da body e tbm não funcionou

Comment: está apontando para:                                                                               <link rel="stylesheet" href="/arbo.social/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>

Comment: quando utiliza Spring MVC não precisa configurar algum arquivo para recursos estáticos e não estáticos ?